# Is it safe to leave a disconnected laptop charger plugged in to its power socket?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, power

When I'm at my desk, my laptop is always plugged in. Sometimes I take it into other rooms of the house. When I disconnect the charger from my laptop, I make sure the charger is unplugged from the power socket too since I assume it's needed for safety reasons.

Is it though? Or is it safe to leave the charger plugged in to the power socket when the laptop isn't connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safe, as long as a child or pet doesn't get hold of the end and put it in their mouth.

Comment: @zx485:  How do you figure that?  The question asks “Is it safe?” and this answer says “It is safe, except …” — it answers the question.  It’s a bad answer, because it doesn’t say anything about how much current or voltage is exposed by the charger cable, or how much it takes to harm a living creature, but it’s a better answer than the other one.

Comment: I don't want to argue about that. I retract my vote.

Comment: @Scott, consider a 120 VAC or 220 VAC extension cord, which is often left with the unused outlets unblocked. By comparison, most external power supplies are 20 VDC or less... not a hazard. In the mouth, it would taste bad or cause an insignificant shock, and it's not enough voltage to feel a shock through unbroken skin.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: I’m not sure what point you’re making.  You seem to be saying that house electric power (called “mains” in England?), at the wall outlet or an extension cord, is much more dangerous than the charger cord — and therefore the answer is wrong.  I guess I agree.  But why address a comment to me?  Address a comment to spikey_richie, and/or down vote the answer, and/or edit the answer to improve it.  I was only asserting that it *is* an answer, not that it is a good one.

Comment: So there's no risk of the charger getting damaged when no laptop is connected for an extended period of time, or any ominous overheating issues?

Comment: Nope. If no current is being drawn (by the laptop), it won't heat up.